# Matrix vs. Linear Algebra

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Currently we have two tags [matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrix) and [linear-algebra](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-algebra).  These tags have a rather large overlap, in fact (after a clean up) of the 30 questions tagged [linear-algebra](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-algebra) the following are the questions *not* tagged with [matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrix)

- [Arnold's Cat Map](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/105362/arnolds-cat-map)
- [Self Referential Polynomials](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/81046/self-referential-polynomials)
- [Linear Independence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/78079/linear-independence)
- [Solve a Linear Equation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/76121/solve-a-linear-equation)
- [Find the Cross Product](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/70506/find-the-cross-product)

And all of these questions are not about matrices, (however some do have methods of solution that involve matrices.)

On the other hand [matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrix), has about 100 questions with only 25 of them being tagged [linear-algebra](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-algebra).

Should one of these tags be a synonym of the other?  If so which one?

Answer (score 15):

### Keep them separate

A good number of the [matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrix) challenges are about grids of numbers that do not represent any linear transformation. Conversely, the five [linear-algebra](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-algebra) challenges you note do not involve matrices, but are about vectorspaces, independence, abstract transformations, etc. Though these are a minority, I think it would not be accurate to tag them [matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrix). So, I just suggest not making them synonyms, and using both tags where both apply.